# Editing package is node_modules has no effect in create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I am trying to work on a package locally that is a dependency in a react project. I want to debug an issue while it's running in the main react project.

simply using `yarn link` creates duplicate versions of react that breaks hooks. (I also tried `yarn link`ing react and react-dom and it get's harry and I was seeing other issues with that)

So I thought to myself, I have an idea. I can just do this:

```bash
rm ./node_modules/<my-package>/dist
ln -s /<path-to-my-dev-package>/dist ./node_modules/<my-package>/dist
```

And that would be the equivalent. I just need to run `yarn build` on my package before testing it in my app.

The problem is, I cannot get yarn to "see" the changes.

I have verified the symlink is there. I have verified the changes in the built files.

yet no matter what I do, the old non symlink'd version is what I see.

I tried:

```bash
yarn cache clean
yarn start
```

But it still see the old/deleted version of my pacakge (that no longer even exists) when I run my project

How can I get it to "refresh" to the new symlink'd build files?

### TLDR

Even if I don't use symlinks.. any change I make to a package in node_modules is not reflected when I run the app.

So real question is, how are these `node_modules` being cached in create-react-app and how can I clear it so that my changes in `node_modules` are seen, so I can debug them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After poking around in the source of `react-scripts`

It seems I need to remove `./node_modules/.cache/default-development` to clear it and reload the changes.